# windows mobile 6.5 sdk don't run under windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, windows-mobile, winapi

I'm on windows 7 and I try to install visual studio 2008 with the windows mobile 6 standard SDK in order to develop application for windows mobile 6.1/6.5.

I've installed visual studio 2008 and it seems to work correctly. When I try to install Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh I get this :

http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/2897/sansrete.png

When I click the prerequites button, I can see that windows 7 is not in the list of the supported operating system !

http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4720/sansreiv.png

Is that realy the reason of my issue ? How can I fix that ?

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution : I have installed visual studio 2008 and you can't install the sdk with that. You need visual studio 2008 **PROFESSIONAL**...

Answer (score 0):

It is fully supported on Windows 7.  You have to install Studio 2008 as well as the SDKs as an Administrator.

Comment: I just try it now, and the result is unchanged... The installation of Studio 2008 is still not recognized when I try to install the SDK :(